# Row doesn't stretch to content on Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, safari

Working on a personal project and am facing a little trouble with compatibility with Safari the middle Card renders in its correct position but at a fixed size. On Chrome it'll scale appropriately with the content but in Safari it'll spill over without stretching the card body at all.

Really tearing my hair out at this one, would appreciate any insights.

```css
/* Links */

a,
a:focus,
a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}


/* Custom default button */

.btn-secondary,
.btn-secondary:hover,
.btn-secondary:focus {
  color: #333;
  text-shadow: none;
  /* Prevent inheritance from `body` */
  background-color: #fff;
  border: .05rem solid #fff;
}


/*
 * Base structure
 */

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #5B4562;
}

.text-highlight {
  color: mediumpurple;
  font-weight: 450;
}

body {
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  color: #fff;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 5rem rgba(0, 0, 0, .5);
}

.cover-container {
  max-width: 52rem;
}


/*
 * Header
 */

.masthead {
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
}

.masthead-brand {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.nav-link {
  padding: .25rem 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  background-color: transparent;
  border-bottom: .25rem solid transparent;
}

.nav-link:hover,
.nav-link:focus {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .25);
}

.nav-masthead .nav-link+.nav-link {
  margin-left: 1rem;
}

a.nav-link {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.active {
  color: #fff;
  border-bottom-color: #fff;
}

@media (min-width: 48em) {
  .masthead-brand {
    float: left;
  }
  .nav-masthead {
    float: right;
  }
}


/*
 * Cover
 */

.cover {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.cover .btn-lg {
  padding: .75rem 1.25rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.row:before,
.row:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<body>
  <div className="cover-container d-flex h-100 p-3 mx-auto flex-column">
    <header className="masthead mb-auto">
      <div className="inner">
        <a href="/"></a>
        <nav className="nav nav-masthead justify-content-center">
          <a>Link Examples</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </header>
    <br/>

    <div className="row">
      <div className="card col-lg-11 ml-5 mr-5 text-dark">
        <div className="card-body">
          <h1 className="display-4">Universal</h1>
          <p className="lead card-text">
            Lots of long text would go here to cause issues!</p>
          <p className="lead">
            <a href="/buy" className="btn btn-lg btn-dark">Purchase Button</a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <br/>

    <footer className="mastfoot mt-auto text-white">
      <div className="inner">
        <p>&copy; Footer</p>
      </div>
    </footer>
  </div>
```

Comment: Your example looks the same in both Chrome and Safari to me.

Comment: Should note, the issues that I've been seeing have been with the mobile version of safari.

Comment: Remove `h-100` from `cover-container` and instead use `min-height: 100%`. Safari seems to prevent the container growing past 100% height, where as Chrome does not. I haven't tested mobile, but this fixes it in MacOS Safari

Comment: Ah all resolved now - do you wanna post an answer so I can resolve it and mark it as the solution?